# How to know the number of Files opened by OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, file, count, openfiledialog

I can retrieve the names of individual files and also I can use count in the looping code to get the required value, but is it possible to know this without the iteration. Perhaps, a **Property** is defined for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length`

Comment: If you want to use Count() as first suggested, make sure you import the correct namespaces in your using section (e.g. using System.Linq).